# router.navigate changes the URL, but is not rendering the component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, redirect

Instead of using `<a href="/my-path/{{my_param}}"></a>` in my template, I am willing to use a function with paramters to redirect me to a page.

So, this is how I built my function in my .ts file:

```
redirectToChat(my_param){
    this.router.navigate(['./my-path/' + my_param ]);
}
```

And how I called it in my template:

```
 <div (click)="redirectToChat(my_param)">
    ...
</div>
```

It changes the URL, but not rendering the component.
I imported this in my component:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
```

And I used it in my constructor: `private router: Router`

Can you help me to render corrctly the component? How else can I redirect the user to the page using a function?

Comment: How does your route path looks like?

Comment: /my_path/:param is my route. So, it's a route with a parameter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing navigate (to component) with navigate by url.
Have you tried navigateByUrl?

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('./my-path/' + my_param);
```

Comment: this still does only refresh the url but does not navigate to the url

Comment: could you fix this ?

Comment: I am having the same problem with both `navigateByUrl` and `navigate`.